# React setAttribute to specific element from .map array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with setting attribute in my component, I want to set class to first element from array which is returned from `createdImages()`.

How I can refer to this array, and then set class?

```
class Slider extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      imagesArray : ['css', 'html', 'javascript']
    };

  };

  createdImages() {
    return this.state.imagesArray.map(image => {
      return <img key={image} src={require(`./img/${image}.png`)} />
   });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="slider">
        { this.createdImages() }
      </div>
    );
  }    
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the attribute the way you describe would mean manipulating the DOM outside of React. Which would work, but probably not the best approach.

The easiest way of doing this is simply adding the current iterator to your mapping. Then for the first element (where `index` is `0`) add your class:

```
createdImages() {
  return this.state.imagesArray.map((image, index) => (
    <img
      key={image}
      className={index === 0 ? 'foo-bar' : ''}
      src={require(`./img/${image}.png`)}
    />
  ));
}
```